# How to use range values as input arguments to shell command

Tags: vba, shell, excel, arguments

I have the following shell code:

```
RetVal = Shell("""C:\pathforprogram.exe""" + "/argument1 /argument2 /savefile=C:\textfile.txt",1)
```

My problem is now that i want /argument1 for example to be read from a cell. So if Cell A1 has the following string /DoThis then i would do the following:

```
ArgumentA = Range("A1").Value

RetVal = Shell("""C:\pathforprogram.exe""" + "ArgumentA /argument2 /savefile=C:\textfile.txt",1)
```

However i get the following error returned:

> ArgumentA is not a valid input command

So it seems that the shell command reads ArgumentA instead of /Dothis.

Is there any solution to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
ArgumentA = Range("A1").value
RetVal = Shell("""C:\pathforprogram.exe""" & ArgumentA & " /argument2 /savefile=C:\textfile.txt", 1)
```

also I suggest you to fully qualify your `Range` object:

```
ArgumentA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much Simoco. And for the suggestion to make the code more rigorous. I have also noticed that for more input arguments i would need to write & ArgumentA & " " & ArgumentB &.